# Applying different style to same control inside different containers

Tags: xaml, styles

Is this possible using Xaml? For example, I have labels inside group boxes and toolbars. I have set labels' foreground color to white using Style in Xaml code.

Background color of the window is black so the group boxes have this background, as well. However, toolbar's background color is System.Media.Colors.Control (or whatever it is by default) and I'd like to keep it that way. The problem is that white isn't the best color on almost white (toolbar).

Is it possible to set Label's foreground color to be different depending on what its container is? And only in one place - in my case inside main window's Window.Resources tag.

Something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ToolBar.Label">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the resources with the control e.g.

```
<ToolBar>
        <ToolBar.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ToolBar.Resources>
    </ToolBar>
```

Then labels in your tool bar will pick the local resource.

Comment: Hi D J. Yes, I'm aware of that. It's just, I really don't want to add this code to every toolbar if it's not absolutely necessary. I think I will change toolbar's background color to something else inside main window's Resource tag if there isn't anyt other way to accomplish this. Thanks.